# Concept of a sript to calculate mouse velocity

Tags: javascript, mouse, velocity

Hi guys:)Could someone explain me this code?I am trying to understand but there is nothing to do.Why this line of code?

```
Math.sqrt(x_dist*x_dist+y_dist*y_dist)/interval;
```

Isn't sufficent this?

```
x_dist+y_dist/interval;
```

I don't understand the concept of this code...

https://jsfiddle.net/vnodkumar1987/ER8qE/

Comment: I think you better read up on [Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The first example calculates the hypotenuse, and in so doing achieves an absolute velocity value of the mouse vector.

The second example will give a bad result unless both x_dist and y_dist are positive.  In other words, if you were moving down and left, or up and right, the second example would have a subtractive effect, and not represent the true overall velocity.  In the case of up and left, the velocity would not only be proportionately incorrect (only useful for comparison purposes), but also result negative sign that you would have to account for.  (I am assuming 0,0 represents the upper left of the mouse-able area and x_max,y_max to be the lower right.)

The Math.sqrt may not be necessary if you are just scaling proportionate velocity, but it certainly is if you want to know true pixels/interval. You would also have to take into account how big a variable container you are working with, but I'm sure it would all fit into a double... unless you were looking for extreme precision.

Imagine you travel in a straight line so that you end up at a point 3 miles West, and 4 miles South in exactly 1 hour.  The velocity answer is not 3+4=7 miles per hour, nor is it-3+4=1 miles per hour.  The correct answer of absolute velocity is the hypotenuse, which would be 5 mph.  sqrt(west^2+south^2)

Example #1 would be the proper code.  Example #2 could be roughly used if you can ignore the sign, and you needed the code to execute very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a pythagorean triangle with the two catethus being *x_dist* and *y_dist*, which are the distance the mouse moved in each of X and Y axis each frame. What that line of code does is to get the magnitude of the delta position vector of the mouse and divide it by some scalar value.

Also, note that sqrt(a^2 + b^2) does **NOT** equal a + b.

EDIT: Not velocity, but delta position.

Comment: I've not understood this:

Comment: "What that line of code does is to get the magnitude of the velocity of the mouse and divide it by some scalar value."

Comment: An other thing I don't understand is how in this function it calculate velocity of the mouse if I stop the mouse for 10 seconds and then I move it for 20 pixel in 1 ms...Does it calculate 20pixel/10001ms?

Comment: @Fistright velocity is a vector which can be represented as (x, y). In 2D space a vector is composed by 2 numbers, one for the length of the vector of the X axis, and one for the Y. The magnitude is the distance from point (0,0) to (x, y). Now we have two points, p1 and p2 respectively. Using pythagorean theorem **a^2 + b^2 = c^2** we can do **d = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)** we know that the catethus are (x - 0) for X, or **a** and (y - 0) for Y, or **b**. Subsituting in equation: magnitude = sqrt(x^2 + y^2). And then divide that value by a number(a scalar value, which is just a number).

Comment: ""Does it calculate 20pixel/10001ms?"" - yes, if *interval* is defined as mouse_stop to mouse_stop.  If *interval* is merely a number of system clicks, then the result is the average speed over the *interval* at line execution.  If this code is an *event handler*, it might provide the mouse_stop to mouse_stop functionality.  But I doubt it, as it can be interrupted by other events, and probably cannot be given exclusive focus.

Comment: Ok but for example:

Comment: @Fistright No, I think the interval is constant, like every 1ms or so, so it would calculate 0px/1ms for each ms you clicked and not moved, and 20px/1ms the frame you moved it. EDIT: It depends of the implementation of interval. In this case I think it's constant.

Comment: If I stop the mouse for 10 seconds and then I move it quickly in the function that 10 seconds will be added and the value of velocity will be wrong...or not?

Comment: only if *interval* is defined as current_system_time - last_event_time

Comment: What does it mean that the interval is constant?Does it take mouse's coordinates every tot of extabilished ms and then calculate the velocity ?

Comment: @SteveRacer  are there other ways to define interval?

Comment: Your code examples do not define *interval*, but we assume that is some sort of time (which is what we need to know to get *velocity*).   velocity COULD be absolute time between code executions, or it could be a fixed time during code execution.  Heck, it could be a fixed number of 7.  The code examples do not explain *interval* derivation.  All we know is that *interval* is the time it took to travel *x_dist* and *y_dist*, if it is to have any meaning.

Comment: Also, keep in mind the code has to be executed for EVERY straight-line mouse move in order to be accurate.  If I move the mouse in a perfect circle, ending back up at my starting point, and THEN execute this code, the result "velocity" will be 0... no matter what *interval* ... even though we know that isn't the truth.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand...so to calculate velocity we need an interval to see mouse position?

Comment: @SteveRacer   Excuse me but I don't understand...so to calculate velocity we need an interval to see mouse position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114171/discussion-between-steveracer-and-fistright).

Answer (score 0):

The velocity is `distance_travelled/time_taken`.

[image: diagram]

Say the pointer moves from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)` as shown in the figure above. The distance travelled is not the sum of the x and y distances.

Summing up x and y assumes that the pointer went from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y1)` and then from `(x2,y1)` to `(x2,y2)`. i.e. the sum of the lengths of the 2 blue lines. But what you need is the length of the black line.

The actual distance travelled is `d` as shown in the figure. Using [Pythagorean theorem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pythagorean+theorem), `d^2 = x_dist^2 + y_dist^2`.

Which leaves you with the line of code you have in the question for the speed

```
Math.sqrt(x_dist*x_dist+y_dist*y_dist)/interval;
```